# How to set an event that occurs on the last day of every month, not just occure on 31 of each month on google calender

Tags: icalendar

How to set an event that occurs on the last day of every month, 
not just occure on 31 of each month on google calender.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take a look at this [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how to ask or answer questions and to learn more about how stackoverflow works.

Answer (score 0):

FREQ=MONTHLY;BYSETPOS=-1

A bit of googling brings up a few related examples.  Try searching on 'ics last day of month' or 'ics recurrence rule' - there are lots of examples in the RFC5545 spec too.